# glediator + PL9823 (WS2812B) + teensy = fail?

Tags: teensy

here is what I got:

- teensy++ 2.0 with code below
- Glediator configured for Glediator_Protocol/Single_Pixels/HL_TL/RGB/B_1000000
- led matrix with the PL9823 leds (80 of them)

I first off have to set the code to 160 on the teensy just to get it to                     at least make the leds change. even when i have it set to that OR the 80 leds, it does not show what is on screen (see video below). I have no clue what to try next.

Code

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 160
const int dataline = PIN_B4;
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() 
{
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
    Serial.begin(1000000); 
    LEDS.addLeds<WS2812B, dataline>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
    for (int p=0;p< NUM_LEDS;p++)
    {
        leds[p] = CRGB::Black;  
        FastLED.show();
    }
}

int serialReadBlocking() 
{
    while (!Serial.available()) 
    {
    }
    return Serial.read(); 
}

void loop() 
{
    while (serialReadBlocking() != 1) 
    {
    } 
    for (long i=0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) 
    {
        leds[i].r = serialReadBlocking();
        leds[i].g = serialReadBlocking();
        leds[i].b = serialReadBlocking();
    }
    FastLED.show();
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6OuMWKtbmo

Answer (score 1):

G'day Guy, What you're building there looks nice. Do you have a circuit diagram you can share? Regarding the code, I've never played with `FastLED.h` but is the `serialReadBlocking` how it deals with the input data? Not that it's wrong, just not what I was expecting.

Two things to look at:

1. Your serial baud rate is a bit odd, 1 million neat. Is that intended? I wouldn't think so. Most common is 9600, I have run projects at 19,200 for giggles, but I doubt that you have it correct there.
2. I see your project you are using multi coloured LEDs with 3+1 pins which in actual fact means you have 240 LEDs (are the last 80 segments/colours all lighting?). If your PC sending the serial stream is expecting 80x single colour LEDs (80 individual LEDS) but you've got 80x tri-colour LEDs (80x3=240 LEDs) you probably aren't lighting them all up. (I only mention this point because I noticed your PC appeared to be sending only one colour, but that could have just been the moment I saw in the video).

edit: I meant to include this link for the teensy serial baud rate info: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_uart.html

Comment: The teensy++2.0 uses a hardware USB built into its AT90USB1286 chip and  completely ignores any baud rate set in the Serial.begin(10000000) line, using instead a 12Mbit/sec rate i. See https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_serial.html

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that, thanks. I don't yet have any Teensy stuff. It is something I've wanted to play with :)